# PHP GET get more one element by one input

Tags: php, get, element

If I have this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hello" value="hey" />
<input type="text" name="one" />
```

And I'll write something, for example: "hey", it will show:

**domain.com/index.php?hello=hey&one=hey**

But, I want to get more element from specific input. For example:

This is my full code:
For e

```
<input type="hidden" name="hello" value="hey" />
<input type="text" name="one" />
<input type="text" name="two" />
```

If I write on "one", it will show:
**domain.com/index.php?hello=hey&element=sometext&one=sometext**
If I write on "two", it will show: **domain.com/index.php?hello=hey&another_element=sometext&two=sometext**

How can I do that?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What happens if you write in both?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "GET" method :

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="hello" value="hey" />
    <input type="text" name="one" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="two" value="2" />
</form>
```

It will create the query string `?hello=hey&one=1&two=2`

Comment: It doesn't match my request, I want to do this thing with one input.

Comment: Is it a problem if they both appear in the query string? if "one" is empty and "two" has the value "2", then it will give you `?one=&two=2` which isn't a problem, or I don't see why.

Comment: So Maybe I'll use more then one <form> tag?

Comment: No, I meant that what you want is possible but seems useless to me. In PHP you can do `if (!empty($_GET['one'])) { ... }` to check if the variable "one" was empty or not. There's usually no need to remove it completely from the URL. (but maybe I didn't understand your question)